# How to avoid having android spinner call itemselectedlistener when setting adapter?

Tags: android, android-spinner

It appears that android's Spinner class (and possibly ListView in general, although I don't know for sure) calls your OnItemSelectedListener's `onItemSelected()` method after you call `setAdapter()`, even if the user hasn't explicitly selected anything yet.

I can see how this would be useful in many situations, but there are times when I only want `onItemSelected()` to be called when an item is actually specifically selected.

Is there a way to control this behaviour and have Spinner NOT call `onItemSelected()` after setting the adapter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used this solution for very long yet so I'm not totally confident that it works as expected, but I've had luck so far with this workaround:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        protected Adapter initializedAdapter = null;

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // Always ignore the initial selection performed after setAdapter
            if( initializedAdapter !=parent.getAdapter() ) {
                initializedAdapter = parent.getAdapter();
                return;
            }

            ...
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: If the user pressed the first item the code above has no effect.

Comment: Same issue I am facing

Answer (score 3):

Add listener to spinner like below:

```
spinner.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run()
    {
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [setTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) and getTag methods, and created a [resource id](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id) called "spinnerstate".

Then whenever I programmatically set the adapter, I set the "spinnerstate" tag to "init", and in the fired event, set it to "ready" and ignore the event. (note my code is Mono for Android se it will look different):

Set Adapter:

```
profileSpn.SetTag (Resource.Id.spinnerstate, "init");
profileSpn.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, items.ToArray ());
```

Item Selected event:

```
    string state = (string)((Spinner)sender).GetTag (Resource.Id.spinnerstate);
    if (state == "init") {
        ((Spinner)sender).SetTag (Resource.Id.spinnerstate, "ready");
        return;
    }
```

I agree that this is not desired behaviour in almost 100% of cases, and I don't think it's good design on the part of Google, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

I did similar things before, I used count value. Using parent adapter object is incomplete because it can be a problem when view is refreshed or `getView()` called again.

Therefore, I recommend that using array of counter.

At first, define array of count in adapter globally.

```
private int isInitializedView[];
```

And then initialize it on getView().

```
isInitializedView[position] = 0;
```

In the selection listener, do something that you want if it already initialized.

```
    holder.mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            isInitializedView[position]++;
            if(isInitializedView[position] > 1) {
                // do someting that you want
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {}
    });
```

(Note that `isInitializedView[position]++;` can be come after `if()` routine, and only trigger event when this value is `>0` . It's your choice.)

Answer (score 0):

I had three spinner in my activity and all spinner adapter data has been filled at runtime(from web-service data after call from `onCreate` method). So it automatically call `onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` method of spinner.
I solved this issue by using [onUserInteraction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction()) method of activity
check this method that user is interacting with spinner or not. if yes then perform the action else not

1. Declare **isUserIntract** boolean variable globally
2. in `onItemSelected` method use following procedure

   If(isUserIntract)
   {

   //perform Action

   }
   else{

   //not perform action

   }
3. use below code in activity

@Override

```
public void onUserInteraction() {
super.onUserInteraction();
isUserIntract = true;
}
```